# Authentication not working on MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, security, authentication, authorization

So I have a MongoDB cluster deployed on 8 VMs (2 config servers, 2 shards with 2 replicas each and 2 mongos instances).
I configured it all from command line and decided to configure the authentication afterwards.
For that I edited the /etc/mongod.conf of the config servers and mongos to enable auth like so:

```
setParameter:
  enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Then I restarted both mongod instances as well as the mongos instances, however, when I connect to a mongos I get the following warning: `Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted`
And when I create a user with only permission to read it can still write to a db...
Is there an error on the configuration file or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you need to enable authentication without any downtime? If not, then simply skip `enableLocalhostAuthBypass` and restart all `mongod/mongos` processes. Did you create a keyfile for [internal authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/)?

Comment: Did you follow this procedure: [Deploy Sharded Cluster with Keyfile Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/)?

Comment: No, I simply created users with the `db.createUser()` method on the mongos instance.
Also no, I'll try and follow that procedure then, thanks!